# I am seeing this error on submitting form Error: query was empty

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("lobbymen_hireus", $con);

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hireus (name, cname, email, telephone)
                      VALUES (ashfaq, muhm, ashfaq@, 1234566)");

if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: we are not a debugger. did you check the value of your query? did you debug?

Comment: Am I the only one who saw the mysql_query done on a mysql_query?

Comment: @jValdron lol no, but this is not the only issue

Comment: Give us the exact error output you are getting. Also you inserting the result of a query the second time - don't

Comment: for adding strings for columns having datatype varchar use single quotes. VALUES ('ashfaq', 'muhm', 'ashfaq@', 1234566)

Answer (score 3):

You need to properly format your strings for insert:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hireus (name, cname, email, telephone)
VALUES ('ashfaq', 'muhm', 'ashfaq@', '1234566')");
```

But that's just the tip of the iceberg with this code...

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of, you will need to put quotes around your values, as they are strings. You are also doing a query on a query, so you need to change $query to this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO hireus (name, cname, email, telephone)
    VALUES ('ashfaq', 'muhm', 'ashfaq@', '1234566')";
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a problem in your query, it should be like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO hireus (name, cname, email, telephone) VALUES ('ashfaq', 'muhm', 'ashfaq@', '1234566')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're executing your query twice (the second time the query result is the query, so false is returned), and you forgot the quotes around your values. it should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO hireus (name, cname, email, telephone) VALUES ('ashfaq', 'muhm', 'ashfaq@', '1234566')";

if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
```